# Unable to export BIRT report to PDF. Error : + org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException

Tags: birt, error-reporting

I've created a sample report in BIRT 4.8 version which I'm unable to export in PDF.
Error: + org.eclipse.birt.report.service.api.ReportServiceException: Error happened while running the report.

I'm able to run the report in BIRT report viewer and also able to download the report in EXCEL, DOCS etc.

Any help in understanding this error is highly appreciated.

Fyi, just recently started using the tool and could export another report in BIRT to PDF format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because of in appropriate placement of grids and tables.
Please check the grids or create a fresh report and check once

Answer (score 1):

Update the latest java/ jre version which is supported by BIRT 4.8 version and then try exporting pdf.

You can see this information on website as well: Pre-requisites: Java 1.7 JDK/JRE.

> http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/